# Is it possible to use MsSQL in PHP without installing sqlsrv drivers?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

We are using MsSql in one of our PHP project. I am able to run it on my local machine by installing sqlsrv drivers. But when we try to move it on to staging server which is linux environment, it is not working as dirvers are not present. Linux server also not supporting these drivers. So is there any possibility to connect to MsSql database independently without drivers?

Server has PHP version 5.x

Comment: I found [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017) interesting article in microsoft docs. it basically sais that it's possible to use Php + MSsql on Linux. I have not checked it though. Edit: I was a bit late writing this commtent. Answer below has more info on the usage.

Comment: Hello Sravan - 
Have you tried dblib extension for PHP. Also while asking questions please provide version information (PHP & MySQL) also, so that its more clear. Happy coding!

Comment: Sure will give a quick look into it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You have at least [the legacy extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php), [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (either with [PDO_DBLIB](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) or [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)). You just need to rewrite your application code accordingly.

It's also worth nothing that SQLSRV [supports Linux](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql#prerequisites) on PHP/7.2 and PHP/7.3.

Comment: In this case in need to use the legacy extension as our servers are still in PHP5.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go with the ODBC Drivers, of course you can install the Microsoft drivers under Linux. These are simple PHP Extensions.

You can download them from PECL (https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv) or Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Here is the official procedure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017